# Добавление и нормально отображение иконок в navbar на мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap4

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, а конкретнее она связана с тем, что при добавлении иконки корзины в `navbar` в мобильной версии кнопка `navbar-toggler` смещается приблизительно к центру всего бара вместо того, чтобы прилегать к корзине слева.

Скриншот:

[image]

Как можно подвинуть переключатель без всяких костылей, если это конечно возможно?
 
Также `float: right` не помогает. С помощью `margin` тоже смысла особого нет, так как ширина экранов разная

Код:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top bg-bronze navbar-white">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" height="50"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="cart cart-mobile">
          <a lass="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-flip-horizontal fa-2x cart-exact"><p class="cart-num">10</p></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Avaleht <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tooted</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="right-menu">
            <div class="login">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sisselogimine</a><i class="fas fa-user fa-2x user-exact" style="color: #138bc6;float: left;"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <div class="language-switcher">
                <div class="dropdown nav-item">
                  <a class="lg-btn nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    ET
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EN</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="cart cart-full">
            <a lass="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-flip-horizontal fa-2x cart-exact"><p class="cart-num">10</p></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Без кода мы вряд ли что-то поймём...

Comment: Какой код нужен? Единственное могу дать код корзины, но у неё нет никаких марджинов или паддингов. Так что проблема в самом bootstrap

Comment: Код Вашего `navbar`'a

Comment: Вставил, извиняюсь что сразу не вставил

Comment: Читайте документацию, пожалуйста, там абсолютно все есть. Ваша проблема связана с вашей невнимательностью при использовании Bootstrap 4. Проблем у Bootstrap 4  в вашем случае никаких нет.